# Correctly convert a string to dictionary with irregular csv in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq

I have a string returned from user input on an aspx page. The first block of c# code works just fine and I can access each dictionary key value pair.

```
string strsvresponse = "name:bob, age:22, city:Wolverhampton, state:West, Midlands, country:United Kingdom"
var dictusrdata = strsvresponse.Split(',')
.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

However, the subtle difference is that another user has decided to add a comma in the state field which throws an error "Index was outside bounds of array".

```
string strsvresponse = "name:bob, age:22, city:Wolverhampton, state:West, Midlands, UK, country:United Kingdom"
var dictusrdata = strsvresponse.Split(',')
.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

I can't stop the user from doing this, however I was wondering if there was a better way to code the string to get key value pairs or access the field:value data?

Thanks
G

Comment: So what should happen if user inputs something without `:`?

Comment: Count number of `,` and number of  `:`. If the number-1 don't match - you know you have a problem.

Comment: That's not a CSV by any definition. It looks like *JSON* without the angle brackets. Its main *dis*advantage is that you *can't* handle commas in fields. How is this string generated? Why not fix the code that creates it to return a JSON string instead? If this string is generated by Javascript, a simple `thatNameObject.toJSON()` would be enough

Comment: There is absolutely no way to distinguish between a comma in the value, and the comma meaning "next key". You'll need to change the way the data is sent to, for example, wrap quotes around the value. Why do you have a custom way of sending data to the server anyway?

Comment: Sorry peeps I'm new to all of this. Amazed by the responses. It does come back in JSON format via api get so I have no control over how the user inputs data. The string starts and ends with curly brackets but I butchered the string to make it a simple csv and it works for 99% of the time. So how do I correctly handle a JSON response in c#? Thanks and sorry for misleading!

Comment: Open the NuGet package manager.  (In VS: Manage NuGet packages, Browse). __Newtonsoft.JSon__ is always on top, it has been  the most popular for years.

Comment: @Twiss show the original string that you get, with all the curly brackets?

Answer (score 3):

First: your format is ambiguous. Use well known and widely supported formats: CSV, JSON, XML or something more strict.

If you can't change format, you must assume something. Let's assume that tags are single words divided by comma and space:

```
var regex = "\\w+:.*?(?=(, \\w+:|$))";
string strsvresponse =
    "name:bob, age:22, city:Wolverhampton, state:West, Midlands, UK, country:United Kingdom";

var dictusrdata = Regex.Matches(strsvresponse, regex)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(a => a.Value.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

Regex `\w+:.*?(?=(, \w+:|$))` explained:

```
\w+ - any word
   : - followed by : (this is TAG)
    .*? - eat all chars lazily

(?= - lookahead assertion
   (
    , \w+: - make sure match is followed by [comma][space]TAG
   | - or
    $ - end of string
   )
)
```

Comment: I thought I knew regex... would you mind breaking regex down to parts and explaining what each one does?

Comment: Added some explanations.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that:

```
string strsvresponse = "name:bob, age:22, city:Wolverhampton, state:West, Midlands, UK, country:United Kingdom";
var result = new Dictionary<String, String>();
var pairs = strsvresponse.Split(',');
for (int i = pairs.Count()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var pair = pairs[i].Split(':');
    if (pair.Length == 2)
    {
        result.Add(pair[0].Trim(), pair[1].Trim());
    }
    else
    {
        pairs[i-1] = pairs[i-1] + pairs[i]; // add comma here if needed
    }
}
return result;
```

this will give you result like this

[image: Dump of dictionary]

Please note that the surplus comma is swallowed for `state`. You can add it back on if you want - see comment. Also this assuming that words after comma but without colon do belong to the previous pair.

Also I agree with other commenters that this is a broken CSV format and you need fix the problem at the source - not allow for this input to happen. But it was fun to solve this little puzzle.

Here is a [DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNEA5v) to play with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string strsvresponse = "name:bob, age:22, city:Wolverhampton, state:West Midlands, dfgdfgfdg,country: United Kingdom";

//First split by ','
var response = strsvresponse.Split(',');

foreach (var item in response)
{
    //After splitting by ':' check if
    //you have necessary values to create KeyValuePair
    var dicVals = item.Split(':');
    if(dicVals.Length != 2)
    {
        //TODO: Log error
        continue;
    }
    dic.Add(dicVals[0], dicVals[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approch could be to write a custom parser in this way you can write your custom logic and control the data processing.

```
        string strsvresponse = "name:bob, age:22, city:Wolverhampton, state:West Midlands, UK, country: United Kingdom";

        string iKey = string.Empty;
        string iValue = string.Empty;
        int iMode = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> dictusrdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < strsvresponse.Length; i++)
        {
            if (iMode == 0)
            {
                if (strsvresponse[i] == ':')
                {
                    iMode = 1;
                } 
                else if (strsvresponse[i] == ',')
                {
                    iKey = string.Empty;
                    iValue = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    iKey += strsvresponse[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (strsvresponse[i] == ',')
                {
                    dictusrdata.Add(iKey.Trim(), iValue.Trim());
                    iKey = string.Empty;
                    iValue = string.Empty;
                    iMode = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    iValue += strsvresponse[i];
                }
            }
        }

        //add last value
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(iKey))
        {
            dictusrdata.Add(iKey.Trim(), iValue.Trim());
        }
```

Comment: You realise this cuts the `,UK` part off?

Comment: yes, as i wrote "in this way you can implement your custom logic" this is an example.. it is not clear?